# Расшарить репозитарий в локальную сеть

Tags: linux, ubuntu, debian, репозиторий, deb

Создал локальный deb-репозиторий. На машине, где он установлен, все работает, пакеты с него устанавливаются.

Что нужно сделать, чтобы его было видно на других машинах в сети?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

установите любой *http-* или *ftp-сервер*, в качестве *docroot-а* настройте в нём каталог, в котором находится репозиторий (в этом каталоге должен быть под-каталог `dists`).

на компьютерах, которым нужен доступ к этому репозиторию, добавляйте такие же строки в `/etc/apt/sources.list`, как вы добавили на той машине, где он находится, только *url* поставьте соответствующий.

т.е., вместо:

```
deb file:/путь/к/репозиторию ...
```

указывайте (для *http-сервера*):

```
deb http://адрес.или.имя.машины.с.репозиторием/ ...
```

или (для *ftp-сервера*):

```
deb ftp://адрес.или.имя.машины.с.репозиторием/ ...
```

Comment: развернул ftp сервер vsftpd, в качестве домашней директории указал папку с каталогом dists. В конфиге указал anonymous_enable=YES. В source list тоже прописал
Через консоль подключаюсь к ftp серверу успешно.
Но когда делаю sudo apt-get upate процесс виснет на получении заголовков.
С чем это может быть связано с неправильной настройкой сервера или с настройками сети?